# Retriving $_SESSION data in codeigniter 2.1

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to retrieve session data and use it inside codeigniter,
I have a php page having this code:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['views']=1;
```

and when i want to retrive it in codeigniter page and it's in another folder using :

```
echo $_SESSION['views'];
```

or

```
echo $this->session->userdata('views');
```

Result is undefined. 
i'm using codeigniter 2 and also using this class.

```
https://bitbucket.org/Molchy/ndb-session-class-for-codeigniter/wiki/Home
```

and thanks.

Comment: If you're using PHP's sessions, make sure you're calling `session_start();` on every page you're using them. CI requires you to load the library before using their sessions. `$this->load->library('session');`.

Comment: I did but same problem.

Comment: btw. why would you use that class that doesn't give you anything you don't already have in CI?

Comment: Because i want to send data from my php page without codeigniter to other page that have codeigniter.

Comment: You don't need that class for that (since it's giving you problems), you can simply check for any PHP sessions once user reaches the CI part of the website.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's sessions ($_SESSION) and CI's sessions **are not** the same.

To set data to CI's session, simply do: `$this->session->set_userdata('views', 1);`

It's all very nicely documented: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: The problem is i'm not using codeigniter in my first page. only pure php. and want to retrieve it in other page that uses codeigniter.

Comment: I see, not the best idea to separate code like that. However, `session_start();` before any headers are sent (that's why it should go to the top of the page) should allow you to retrieve PHP's session data. However, you'd make your life easier if you convert that first page to CI.

Comment: The first page is joomla page and i'm using codeigniter inside it using iframe. I did put session_start(); in both pages but same problem.

Comment: You should've said that in your question. Without seeing the whole structure, I can just tell you to look where and when you set the session data and where and when you read it; session_start() *has* to work, you're maybe reading the session before it's there, or not setting it properly.

Comment: I put session_start(); in both pages and in first page $_SESSION['views']=1; and 2nd page var_dump($_SESSION); the result is array(0) { } .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use this in Codeignitor

To set

```
$this->session->userdata('views',1);
```

To get

```
echo $this->session->userdata('views');
```

If you are using php session then you do the following

To set

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['views']=1;
```

To get

```
echo $_SESSION['views'];
```

Comment: 1) To set CI session: `$this->session->set_userdata('view', 1)`; 2) That's already what OP does; must be kept in mind to call `session_start()` everywhere $_SESSION is used, so in the second snippet too